# How to get rid of element from <xsl:copy-of>

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Am trying to display XML content in an HTML using XSLT.
Am using

```
<xsl:copy-of select = "childNode">
</xsl:copy-of>
```

When I used the above one, it will display the attribute as well.

```
<childNode>
<Team>
<TeamName>Team-A</TeamName>
</Team>
<Team>
<TeamName>Team-B</TeamName>
</Team>
<Team>
<TeamName>Team-C</TeamName>
</Team>
</childNode>
```

I don't want to display  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any attribute in your XML sample. If you only want to copy the contents of the `childNode` element then you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="childNode/*"/>` or perhaps better write a template

```
<xsl:template match="childNode">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xsl:copy` instead of `xsl:copy-of` to copy just the selected node.

Use `xsl:apply-templates` to gain control over how child elements are handled through the definition of templates matching the children.

If you want to copy the `childNode` element along with its attributes and add some elements without going the (generally preferred) `xsl:apply-templates` route, try:

```
<xsl:copy select="childNode">
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <!-- add further content here as needed -->
</xsl:copy>
```

Possibilities abound but you'll have to clarify your question if none of these answers meet your needs.